# Веб-браузер, сохранение всего открытого сайта(со всеми ресурсами) в памяти веб-браузера в файл

Tags: веб-сайт

Например я сижу на сайте и мне понравилась анимация(WebGL), но на этот момент я не могу разобраться как ее сохранить и хочу оставить это на потом, сохранив сайт со всеми ресурсами в памяти веб-браузера в файл, чтоб в дальнейшем его открыть и продолжить(если можно с того же места), **типа как снапшот у виртуалки**.
Я хотел бы многие сайты так сохранять на будущее, если мне в них что-то надо, **даже, если их закрыли**.
Веб-браузер Opera.
Если нельзя, подскажите, если можно, как по другому, именно как я описал **выше**.

Comment: При сохранении в firefox можно выбрать вариант "Вебстраница, полностью", это сохранит не только саму страницу, но и ресурсы в папку (видел css, js, png)

Comment: не в тему, это я и так знаю